# Can't set JSP as welcome file in the GAE Guestbook example

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

i'm following the example here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps

so i created a really basic jsp file:

```
<html>
<body>
testing

</body>
</html>
```

and I'm trying to make this the welcome page, like it says in the tutorial:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

but it doesn't get called at. when I go to `http://localhost:8888` it's as if it's missing a file (i renamed index.html. when there is index.html - it displays it).

when i visit `http://localhost:8888/guestbook.jsp` i can see the jsp file with no problem

UPDATE: this happens only on my development server. when i deployed to google app engine, it works as expected:

http://test-ishener.appspot.com/

Comment: Which web server do you use in your local system? Google app Engine Launcher or Any other server?

Comment: I think it's Google app Engine Launcher. I havn't installed anything else

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are not storing JSP in root folder, please show your project directory structure.

Also if you have multiple matches in welcomefile lists say:

```
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
```

then first matching will be executed ie index.html, if this is the case either move guestbook.jsp to first or remove index.html welcome-file tag

Comment: it's at the same place index.html is (at least according to the tree in eclipse). I mean it's under war

Comment: Try restarting the server and eclipse.

Comment: how do i restart the server? is restarting eclipse enough?

Comment: @MosheShaham.. please see my edited answer and let me know if you are having that thing..

Comment: for your edit: but i showed you my welcome-file-list tag. it has only the jsp file